# How to snatch a piece of paper?

Tags: modeling, physics

I want to rip it from top to bottom. Maybe I can also do hand animation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you've got? It will be easier to help you if you post some screenshots of your current progress.

Comment: if you look closely the first image, in the top of the page, it seems there's already a sort of cut... maybe it was a sort of fake ripping...